# Find out when SECONDARY became PRIMARY

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

Let's say I have a three server setup. Two servers store data, and a server is an arbiter.

Last week, my 'PRIMARY' server went down, and as expected the 'SECONDARY' was promoted and things continued working as expected.

However, I'm now debugging another bug in my application that I *think* might be related to this change in the replication setup.

Is there any way I can find out (from the logs or whatnot) **WHEN** exactly the election occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find in the logs (of the new 'PRIMARY') the following lines:

```
2018-08-02T03:56:49.817+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Standing for election
2018-08-02T03:56:49.818+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] not electing self, ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal:27017 has same OpTime as us: { : Timestamp 1533182831000|1 }
2018-08-02T03:56:49.818+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] possible election tie; sleeping 445ms until 2018-08-02T03:56:50.263+0000
2018-08-02T03:56:50.263+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Standing for election
2018-08-02T03:56:50.265+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] not electing self, ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal:27017 has same OpTime as us: { : Timestamp 1533182831000|1 }
2018-08-02T03:56:50.265+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] running for election; slept last election, so running regardless of possible tie
2018-08-02T03:56:50.265+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] received vote: 1 votes from ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal:27017
2018-08-02T03:56:50.265+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] election succeeded, assuming primary role
2018-08-02T03:56:50.265+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to PRIMARY
```

You can see the election took place at 3:56am UTC.

I advise you use the `less` tool to search in your log file:

```
less /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

Then, navigate at the end of the file using <kbd>G</kbd>, then search backward with <kbd>?</kbd>, and search for *'Standing for election'*.